# Best Run/Debug Configuration for plain JavaScript in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am new to JavaScript but already know Python. On https://onecompiler.com/javascript I can easily type JavaScript code such as

```
console.log("Hello World")
```

and it logs Hello World in the console.

However, I recently installed WebStorm , but I don't know what Run/Debug Configuration I should choose to start with (I just want to type plain JavaScript):

[image: Run/Debug Configuration]

The image shows a list of configurations, however, none of them are called just JavaScript. What should I choose to just type plain JavaScript and be able to run the code?

Answer (score 1):

For plain javascript the right configuration is [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html). WebStorm auto-creates it for you when you right-click a `.js` file and choose **Run** or **Debug**.

If you javaScript code is supposed to be run in browser, you need creating `*.html` file that will be used as your app entry point, link your javascript to this file with the `<script>` tag and then use either **Run** or **Debug** from `.html` file right-click menu - the corresponding [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration will be created and started.